# How to use a $_POST variable in an mysqli-query? (php)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I'm currently learning php and am testing around with sqli queries.
I want to have an input field where a number can be entered. This number is used in the sql-query. Unfortunately it doesn't work the way I want.
The text field is stored in index.php as this:

```
<form method="post" action="handler.php">
<input type="text" name="idEingabe">
<input type="submit" value="Abfrage für eingegebene ID starten">
</form>
```

In handler.php, I'm using

```
$stridEingabe = $_POST["idEingabe"];
```

And the query contains:

```
$query = 'SELECT name, beschreibung FROM uebersicht WHERE id = "$stridEingabe"'; 
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
/* Array ausgeben */
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    printf ("<b>%s</b> <br>%s<br> <br>", $row["name"],  $row["beschreibung"]);

}

/* free result set */
mysqli_free_result($result);
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Unfortunately I don't get any results when I enter the number into the text box and click the submit-button. But if I write the number in the query without using $stridEingabe, I'm getting the results.

Where is the mistake?
Thanks a lot

Comment: the problem here is, you're querying twice, resulting in a syntax error that MySQL is throwing in the background.

Comment: you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing that an answer's been submitted before this, thought I'd put one in too and based on a comment I left under the question.

One of the problems here is, you're querying twice which is a **major** issue, resulting in a syntax error that [MySQL is throwing in the background](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php), but you're not listening for it. Plus, your quoting method which I've modified below, just in case it is a string; which we don't know at this time.

```
$query = 'SELECT name, beschreibung FROM uebersicht WHERE id = "$stridEingabe"'; 

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^

/* Array ausgeben */
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    printf ("<b>%s</b> <br>%s<br> <br>", $row["name"],  $row["beschreibung"]);

}
```

what you want is to remove `= mysqli_query($con, $query)` and add error checking:

```
$query = "SELECT name, beschreibung FROM uebersicht WHERE id = '".$stridEingabe."'"; 

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

if ($result) {
/* Array ausgeben */
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    printf ("<b>%s</b> <br>%s<br> <br>", $row["name"],  $row["beschreibung"]);

    }

} // brace for if ($result)

// else statement for if ($result)
else{
    echo "There was an error: " .mysqli_error($con);
}
```

Or, better yet using `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.

```
$stridEingabe = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["idEingabe"]);
```

- Although prepared statements are best.

---

Plus, in regards to SQL injection which is something you're open to,  should be using [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

**Footnotes:**

Make sure you are indeed using `mysqli_` to connect with and not another MySQL API such as `mysql_` or PDO to connect with. Those different APIs do not intermix with each other.

I say this because, the connection method is unknown in your question.

Plus, if you're using your entire code inside the same file, then you should be using a conditional statement for your POST array, otherwise it will thrown a notice immediately on page load; *assuming error reporting is enabled on your system.*

- The notice would be "Undefined index idEingabe..."

I.e.:

```
if(!empty($_POST['idEingabe'])){...}
```

Another thing; if your inputted value is an integer, you can use the following functions to make sure they are integers and not a string, if that is what the ultimate goal is:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php - `is_int()`
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php - `is_numeric()`

and using a conditional statement in conjunction with those.

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! It's working now and I get the results I  expected.

Answer (score 0):

Two things, first your quotes are wrong, and second, with your code you are vulnerable to sql code injection attacks, try this instead:

```
$stridEingabe = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["idEingabe"]);
$query = "SELECT name, beschreibung FROM uebersicht WHERE id='$stridEingabe'";
```

Comment: Just to point out: the quotes are wrong for PHP - `'`-quoted strings do not interpolate variables. but mysql itself won't care. `"foo"` and `'foo'` are the same to mysql.

Comment: Variables are not replaced with the variable contents unless the string is quoted with " instead of '. So, quoting with ' makes the query hold the variable name instead of the variable contents.

Comment: yeah, I misread your answer the first time around, so... fixed up my comment.

Comment: Then using " makes the query hold the variable contents and using ' makes the query hold the variable name (as a string), that's right ?

Comment: Yes, if a word starts with $ and there is a variable named as that word, and the variable has a pasteable content (a string, a number etc, not objects) then it gets replaced with the variable contents. If the variable is null the most likely that will apear in the query, a null word.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not concatenating the $string to the query

Use something like

```
$query = 'SELECT name, beschreibung FROM uebersicht WHERE id = ''.$stridEingabe.'';
```

Or use double quotes which is way more acceptable

```
$query = "SELECT name, beschreibung FROM uebersicht WHERE id = '$stridEingabe'";
```

And try to use only the $results declared in the if statement to avoid double queries.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong quotes. try this:

```
 $query = "SELECT name, beschreibung FROM uebersicht WHERE id = '$stridEingabe'";
```