# Passing data from `HTML` Login form to `PHP` for data retrivel from `MySQL' database

Tags: php, mysql

The below is the code of the PHP file that I creaed.

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","toor","mylib")
or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<h1>PHP connect to MySQL</h1>
</body>
</html>


<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM book WHERE bookid IN  (SELECT bookid FROM studentbook  WHERE studid =
$_POST['stuid'])";
mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database.');
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
foreach($row as $a)
    print($a." ");
?>
```

Now, I am looking to get `studid` from HTML login page and passing it 
to the PHP file using `POST` method to retrieve data corresponding to the value(studid) entered, from `MySQL` database - I mean using `mysqli_query()` function.

But when I try to run the code which I have shown above, I came up  with below `Error`:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/connectivity.php on line 13`

**Please guide me on the following:**

1) How to get values from `Login page` and pass it to the `PHP file` using `post` method?

2) How to correct the above mentioned error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a $\_POST variable in an mysqli-query? (php)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30360721/how-to-use-a-post-variable-in-an-mysqli-query-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the below code must work and your error might be solved,

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","toor","mylib")
or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

/* get values from form */
$sid = $_REQUEST['stuid'];

/* execute query */
$query = "SELECT * FROM book WHERE bookid IN  (SELECT bookid FROM studentbook  WHERE studid = '$sid')";
mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database.');
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
foreach($row as $a)
    print($a." ");
?>
```

Now your data from Login Page would get stored in `$sid` variable and will be interpolated in the query. So, if your database is connected and everything works fine, you could see the output stored in `$row` array.